# How to disable/delete network manager

Tags: centos6, linux-networking

I'm on `CentOS 6.4 64 bit` in rescue mode and network manager keeps overwriting my `resolv.conf` and the command `chkconfig` is "unknown" so how do I disable/delete network manager?

Answer (score 4):

To check to make sure NetworkManager is installed run `rpm -qa | grep chkconfig`

However, I'm going to assume you `su`'ed to root rather than `su -`. Without `su -` `/sbin/chkconfig` won't be in your path and you'll receive that error.

1. Stop NetworkManager: `service NetworkManager stop`
2. Remove Network Manager from startup Services: `chkconfig
   NetworkManager off`
3. Add the default Net Manager to startup: `chkconfig network on`
4. Start the default Manager: `service network start`

Comment: Make sure to do this from a local console because you will disconnect yourself. Otherwise, just do steps 2 and 3 and then reboot.

Answer (score -1):

I would just suggest making `resolv.conf` immutable. `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`.

You may want to add a comment to the file first, so you'll remember that you made it immutable if you ever try to change it.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote? This is the safest and simplest solution.